# PostgreSQL ANY IN subselect result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tasks t  WHERE (769, 2) IN 
  (SELECT c3.id FROM categories c3 JOIN tasks_categories tc ON c3.id = tc.category_id WHERE tc.task_id = t.id)
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: subquery has too few columns
```

looks like the reason is that I'm trying to check `(769, 2)` in the result of subquery.
How to rewrite this query in order to check:

```
ANY of (769, 2) in the result of (subselect) ?
```

Comment: just write it the other way around... `where (subquery returning 1 value) in (769, 2)`, surely?

Comment: the issue with this approach is that subquery may potentially return more than 1 value

Comment: then I would imagine you need to materialise the `(769, 2)` as a table (CTE, function, etc.) and `join` to that, but maybe someone else knows a better way.

Comment: `where exists (select...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` . . . and probably don't need `select distinct`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tasks t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM categories c3 JOIN
                   tasks_categories tc
                   ON c3.id = tc.category_id
              WHERE tc.task_id = t.id AND c3.id IN (769, 2)
             );
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` just incurs additional overhead -- and should not be needed assuming that `tasks` has no duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks! Is also there any difference to test `c3.id IN (769, 2)` versus `tc.category_id IN  (769, 2)` ?

Comment: @alexanoid . . . Not in this case.  You are using an `inner join` and the `on` clause ensures that they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rewrite the query in below format,

```
   SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tasks t
JOIN tasks_categories tc ON (tc.task_id = t.id)
JOIN categories c3 ON (c3.id = tc.category_id)
where  c3.id in (769, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One question - how to properly get `c3` in the query you have provided?

Comment: Edited the query to join with `categories` C3 table as well. Please use the updated query